# Handing singularity of numerical integral to high precision

Tags: numerical-integration, singularity

Consider the integral

```
    int[z] = Integrate[(2 x^2 - 1) (\[Pi] Sqrt[1 - x^2])^-1 
(2 y^2 -  1) (\[Pi] Sqrt[1 - y^2])^-1 Log[z Abs[x - y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

This integral can be done analytically, and gives the same answer

int[z] = -1/4

for any z. Let us now try to compute it numerically

```
  Nint[z] :=   NIntegrate[(2 x^2 - 1) (\[Pi] Sqrt[1 - x^2])^-1 (2 y^2 - 
    1) (\[Pi] Sqrt[1 - y^2])^-1 Log[z Abs[x - y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y,-1,1}]
```

for z=1 gives the low precision answer

```
Nint[1] = -0.250002
```

while for z>1 it fails to evaluate. Increasing precision does not seem to drastically improve the situation. I suspect the problem is the singularities when

```
x,y=1,-1
```

but I have not been able to successfully implement this yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Using `"DuffyCoordinates"` might be one thing to try to weaken the singularities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force, but only takes a second:

```
Block[{z = 1},
 NIntegrate[(2 x^2 - 1) (π Sqrt[1 - x^2])^-1 (2 y^2 - 1) *
   (π Sqrt[1 - y^2])^-1 Log[z Abs[x - y]],
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, (*x,*) 1}, (* specify singularity y == x: unnecesary *)
  MaxRecursion -> 20, Method -> "GaussKronrodRule" (* uses open sampling *)
  ]
 ]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

```
(*  -0.25  *)
```

`NIntegrate::slwcon` is just a warning, not an indication of error.  It should be expected in this case.

*Response to comment:*

Maybe it's worth outlining my thought process in the present case.  A general discussion of method selection is beyond the scope of an SE answer.  If you get to know the `NIntegrate` tutorials, as @J.M. suggests, you'll get to know the tools at hand and the examples in which they are effective.  Then you're more than halfway to understanding how to approach numerical integration in *Mathematica*.  "There is no royal road to geometry," and however you learn about numerical integration, it takes considerable time.

So first of all, I wasn't sure what would work.  I didn't think the inverse square roots and the logarithmic singularity looked too bad, but multivariate integration is still a bit of a mystery to me (in terms of what sort of integrand causes trouble.  The first thing that stuck out was the diagonal singularity along `y == x`.  The recursive subdivision divides the integration domain into rectangles which would be unlikely to be successful, since the singularity would cut across the rectangles.  So I thought I should explicitly identify the singularity by including `x` in `{y, 0, x, 1}` (this turns out to be unnecessary, as I just now discovered).  Testing just this alteration leads to overflow, so the change does have an effect.

I know in single-variable numerical integration, such singularities are not that bad and can be handled by a good open-sampling rule such as Gauss-Kronrod.  (The function is analytic between the singularities, and previous experience with inverse square root and logarithmic singularities has shown me it might work well enought.)  So I decided to try it.  I didn't know it would work until it did.  Since it did, I stopped thinking about the problem until....

Until the OP commented and I wondered if the automatic symbolic processing might identify the singularity without my help.  Removing `x` from `{y, 0, x, 1}` shows that manually identifying the singular locus `y == x` was unnecessary.

Comment: btw, how do you know in each situation whether to use super high precision, multidimensionalrule, GaussKronrodRule, etc? is it just guess and check, or is there some intuition i can learn?

Comment: @esches, the [advanced documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html) for `NIntegrate[]` is a more-or-less complete guide on how to choose a `Method` for a particular problem, depending on its special features.